# Embed pdf in Electron app with no toolbar

Tags: pdf, electron

I must be missing something very obvious, but after several hours on SO and in the electron docs trying different things, I've not found the right solution.

For an electron app, I have 4 pdfs: 3 are going to be packaged with the electron app, 1 will come from an external website. I need to be able to display each of them at full-screen, with no toolbars or other "fluff".  Each is exactly 1 "screen" in size, and this is for a VERY restricted audience so I can guarantee the viewing conditions/technology used. In terms of the needed functionality, these pdfs could just be giant images. However.  Due to Reasons(TM) I cannot convert them to any other (easier to use) format.

I am currently using a BrowserWindow, and it works 80%. I can see the pdf just fine, but it's zoomed and still has a toolbar. (This will be displayed in portrait orientation, hence the odd dimensions)

```
$('#btn_0-0').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        openPDF("./app/assets/docs/TreatmentLandscape.pdf")
    })

    function openPDF(filePath) {
        let pdfWindow = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({
            width: 1080,
            height: 1920,
            webPreferences: {
                plugins: true
            }
        });

        pdfWindow.loadFile(filePath)

        pdfWindow.setMenu(null);
        pdfWindow.on('closed', function() {
            pdfWindow = null
        })
    }
```

tl;dr Another person looking for how to do frameless embedded pdfs in electron. Help :(

Comment: Would a generic `openPDF(path)` function that opens a maximised, frameless window (or framed window with only minimise, maximise / restore, close buttons. IE: No menu) be what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, PDF documents can be saved at actual size, fit width , etc so I think the expanding out of the PDF document to fit the window is PDF dependant. That is easy to solve by saving the embedded PDF's to your desired view size. The online PDF may be a different story though.